# Elastic search does not start after installing x-pack

Tags: elasticsearch

I installed x-pack for Elastic Search 6.2.2 and I can't start Elastic search any more. It shows the following error:

[2018-03-01T19:56:55,884][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to load plugin class [org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin]
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:563) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]

Comment: Hello, can you post the entire exception please? this could be the same story than https://discuss.elastic.co/t/failed-to-load-plugin-class-org-elasticsearch-xpack-core-xpackplugin/120627.

Comment: I have found this PR https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/28278 which describing issue with cgroup v2. Faced this exception during update to Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Have you found it's reason?